# Rasterstats not working on raster

Tags: python, geojson, rasterio, rasterstats

I am trying to analyze a GeoTiff file with some geojson regions and rasterstats. But rasterstats doesn't seem to work.

I suspect that is something related with the GeoTiff file, since I am using a new source of files.

```
from rasterstats import zonal_stats
area = './cuenc_3105.geojson'
geotiff = './RN1_Lq_000_250_20220407213000.tif'
estadisticas_cuenca = zonal_stats(area
                                  , geotiff,
                                  stats="count min mean max median nodata unique")
print(estadisticas_cuenca[0]['mean'])
zs = zonal_stats(area, geotiff, band=1,stats="count min mean max median nodata unique")
print(zs)

# Plot of raster 
import rasterio
from matplotlib import pyplot
src = rasterio.open(geotiff)
pyplot.imshow(src.read(1), cmap='pink')
pyplot.show()
```

Output:

```
(my_satpy_env) ➜  Hidro git:(master) ✗ python for_question.py                           
/home/smn/anaconda3/envs/my_satpy_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rasterstats/io.py:313: UserWarning: Setting nodata to -999; specify nodata explicitly
  warnings.warn("Setting nodata to -999; specify nodata explicitly")
/home/smn/anaconda3/envs/my_satpy_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rasterstats/main.py:264: UserWarning: Warning: converting a masked element to nan.
  feature_stats['nodata'] = float((featmasked == fsrc.nodata).sum())
None
/home/smn/anaconda3/envs/my_satpy_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rasterstats/io.py:313: UserWarning: Setting nodata to -999; specify nodata explicitly
  warnings.warn("Setting nodata to -999; specify nodata explicitly")
/home/smn/anaconda3/envs/my_satpy_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rasterstats/main.py:264: UserWarning: Warning: converting a masked element to nan.
  feature_stats['nodata'] = float((featmasked == fsrc.nodata).sum())
[{'count': 0, 'min': None, 'mean': None, 'max': None, 'median': None, 'nodata': nan, 'unique': None}]
```

I attach info about my raster next wit gdalinfo and rio info

```
gdalinfo  RN1_Lq_000_250_20220407213000.tif      
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: RN1_Lq_000_250_20220407213000.tif
       RN1_Lq_000_250_20220407213000.tif.aux.xml
Size is 720, 720
Coordinate System is:
PROJCRS["Azimuthal Eqdist",
    BASEGEOGCRS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
            ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        ID["EPSG",4326]],
    CONVERSION["Modified Azimuthal Equidistant",
        METHOD["Modified Azimuthal Equidistant",
            ID["EPSG",9832]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",18.9724200591445,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",-91.1726200394332,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["easting",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]],
        AXIS["northing",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
Origin = (-249998.305064644257072,249998.305064693558961)
Pixel Size = (694.439999999987549,-694.439736290863380)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_DATETIME=2022:04:07 21:30:00
  TIFFTAG_IMAGEDESCRIPTION=IRIS RAIN1 1CUARTO_D_HO
  TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE=IRIS 9.1.0
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( -249998.305,  249998.305) ( 93d34'48.24"W, 21d12'52.69"N)
Lower Left  ( -249998.305, -249998.305) ( 93d30'57.88"W, 16d41'57.13"N)
Upper Right (  249998.495,  249998.305) ( 88d45'54.62"W, 21d12'52.69"N)
Lower Right (  249998.495, -249998.305) ( 88d49'44.98"W, 16d41'57.13"N)
Center      (   0.0949354,  -0.0000000) ( 91d10'21.43"W, 18d58'20.71"N)
Band 1 Block=720x41 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
  Min=0.001 Max=65.744 
  Minimum=0.001, Maximum=65.744, Mean=3.357, StdDev=6.421
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=65.744003295898
    STATISTICS_MEAN=3.3574435591375
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0.0010000000474975
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=6.4207413039405
    STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=6.132
```

rio info

```
rio info RN1_Lq_000_250_20220407213000.tif
{"bounds": [-249998.30506464426, -249998.30506472808, 249998.49493534677, 249998.30506469356], "colorinterp": ["gray"], "count": 1, "crs": "PROJCS[\"Azimuthal Eqdist\",GEOGCS[\"WGS 84\",DATUM[\"WGS_1984\",SPHEROID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"7030\"]],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"6326\"]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0],UNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"9122\"]],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"4326\"]],PROJECTION[\"Azimuthal_Equidistant\"],PARAMETER[\"latitude_of_center\",18.9724200591445],PARAMETER[\"longitude_of_center\",-91.1726200394332],PARAMETER[\"false_easting\",0],PARAMETER[\"false_northing\",0],UNIT[\"metre\",1,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"9001\"]],AXIS[\"Easting\",EAST],AXIS[\"Northing\",NORTH]]", "descriptions": [null], "driver": "GTiff", "dtype": "float32", "height": 720, "indexes": [1], "interleave": "band", "lnglat": [-91.1726191379429, 18.97242005914434], "mask_flags": [["all_valid"]], "nodata": null, "res": [694.4399999999875, 694.4397362908634], "shape": [720, 720], "tiled": false, "transform": [694.4399999999875, 0.0, -249998.30506464426, 0.0, -694.4397362908634, 249998.30506469356, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0], "units": [null], "width": 720}
```

Comment: Your raster and vectors need to be in the same coordinate system. Is your geojson in a different CRS?

Comment: Thanks, not quite sure. The Geojson field crs has the next info: "crs": {"type": "name"
    , "properties": {"name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"}}. After reprojecting the geotiff to 'EPSG:4326' it seems that rasterstats is working fine now.